# Does exporting an Activity in Android allow other applications to also call any public methods from that Activity?

Tags: android, android-manifest, public, android-security

Setting "exported=true" in the AndroidManifest allows that particular Activity to be launched by other applications. Does this also allow other applications to call ANY of the public methods inside that exported Activity manually? If so, how would the code to do that look like?

Answer (score 1):

Please, read official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) carefully:

> This element sets whether the activity can be launched by components
>   of other applications — `true` if it can be, and `false` if not. If
>   `false`, the activity can be launched only by components of the same
>   application or applications with the same user ID. If you are using
>   intent filters, you should not set this element `false`. If you do so,
>   and an app tries to call the activity, system throws an
>   `ActivityNotFoundException`. Instead, you should prevent other apps from
>   calling the activity by not setting intent filters for it.
>
> If you do not have intent filters, the default value for this element
>   is `false`. If you set the element `true`, the activity is accessible
>   to any app that knows its exact class name, but does not resolve when
>   the system tries to match an implicit intent.
>
> This attribute is not the only way to limit an activity's exposure to
>   other applications. You can also use a permission to limit the
>   external entities that can invoke the activity (see the permission
>   attribute).